# Sublime Text 2 gives PATH error when trying to run a Grunt build system

Tags: ruby, macos, node.js, sublimetext2, gruntjs

I've created this build system for Sublime Text 2 to run my Grunt project:

```
{

"cmd": ["grunt"] ,  
"selector": ["source.js", "source.less", "source.json"] ,
"working_dir": "${project_path}/MyProject" ,
"path": "/Users/me/.nvm/v0.10.0/bin",
"shell": true

}
```

Everytime I try to build, I get this error:

```
Warning: You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for
this task to work. More info:
```

Despite the fact that I've installed both `Ruby` and `Sass`, and both are available in the terminal. Also, I've tried `"echo $PATH"` and it looks ok...

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Users/me/.venvburrito/bin:/Users/me/.nvm/v0.8.22/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

Why can't sublime seem to access my environmental variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"path"` property will overwrite the existing path. You'll need to either remove the property or manually add in the path to the Sass binary. You can find it using `which sass`.

Example:

`"path": "/usr/local/bin/:/Users/me/.nvm/v0.10.0/bin"`

Comment: I'm not using compass. I'm using a gruntfile with grunt-contrib-sass and grunt-contrib-cssmin. Does your answer still apply?

Comment: My path property now looks like this `/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/sass:/Users/me/.nvm/v0.10.0/bin` but I'm still getting the same error. I also tried adding `/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby` Same error. Am I missing a required path? Does the path order matter?

Comment: Got it working. Check my answer above for details. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. I had to add this to the "path" property:

```
"/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby:/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/sass:/Users/me/.nvm/v0.10.0/bin"
```

Obviously you'll have to replace "me" with your own name. Thanks to Sindre Sorhus for pointing me in the right direction.